# Working with big numbers in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Consider I have this number: **123456789012345**.

And want to show it using this semi-code:

```
QString s;
QTextStream ss(&s);

int n = 123456789012345;
ss << n;
lineEdit -> setText(s);
```

It shows an incorrect number (a negative number) and works well only up to 10 digits.

How to make it work to 15 digits correctly please?

Comment: Use a larger data type. `123456789012345` is larger than the maximum value that can fit into `int`. Use a `long long` or `unsigned long long` if the value will only be positive.

Comment: [Here's a general sizing chart for reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). Note most types are defined in terms of "at least". This means all of the integer types could be the same size: at least 64 bits. Fun, huh? Also look into [Fixed Width Integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) if you need a guarantee.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Sorry I was very new in Qt. :D

Comment: The question has absolutely nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: From Qt 5.4 you can specify CONFIG += c++14 in your .pro file. Then you can write your values in a more readable way with a digit seperator. int n = 123'456'789; etc.

Comment: What for a floating point variable? for example I want to have a *double* for obtaining the most precision like: 0.00000000012345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, an `int` is too small to hold a value with that many digits. I personally prefer to be explicit with what I want, so I'd use either `quint64` or `uint64_t`. You also don't need the text stream just to put a number in a string, there is a function for this:

```
quint64 n = 123456789012345;
lineEdit->setText(QString::number(n));
```

Comment: What for a floating point variable please? for example I want to have a double for obtaining the most precision like: 0.00000000012345

Comment: @franky - it is the same function, it is overloaded for all numerical types. Just pass a double instead.

Comment: You say, for example, I can use it this way: `quint64 d = 0.00000000012345;   lineEdit -> setText(QString::number(d));` and it will be shown in lineEdit as it is with that precision?

Comment: @franky - it would have to be a `double` not a `qint` - the int is an integer, a whole number. Also, the foating point number will have to be able to accurately represent the number, which is not always possible, as IEEE reals have a discrete level of precision.

Comment: I didn't get your talks, sorry. Do you mean we have only *double* as the most accurate precision floating point number?

Comment: I mean that the double is not a real "real" number - it cannot represent just about any value. It is steps of precision, like the integer can go no less than 1 up or down, the same applies to doubles and floats, it is just that the step is much much smaller. Also the larger the number, the larger the step, for example if you use doubles to measure cosmic scale distances there will be a lot of rounding errors accumulating with each subsequent calculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134927/discussion-between-franky-and-ddriver).

Answer (score 2):

Just specify a data type that is able to hold these number of digits like `unsigned long long`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long long n = 123456789012345;
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cout << n;
}
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/169fe26c254707a9)

`QTextStream` should behave the same way as `std::ostream` does.

Check further in [qulonglong](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qulonglong-typedef) and [`QTextStream & QTextStream::operator<<(qulonglong i)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-13)

Comment: Thanks. +1 for your solution. And please change your answer's format to Qt so that I can give it the correct answer vote.

Comment: @franky I hope that's related enough now.